# Meteor Login contra LDAP

Tags: meteor, ldap

Estoy desarrollando por primera vez en un entorno Ionic + Angular + Meteor y estoy ahora mismo atascado intentando que los usuarios se acrediten contra un servidor LDAP.

Estoy usando el paquete typ:accounts-ldap y tal y como explica en su documentación en la parte servidor expone una variable global LDAP_DEFAULTS.

Mi servidor ahora mismo no tiene nada más que lo inicial, puesto que está en fase muy inicial:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
  LDAP_DEFAULTS.url = "ldap://ldap.*************.es";
  LDAP_DEFAULTS.port = 3189
});
```

Pero me tira el error 'LDAP_DEFAULTS no se encuentra'. ¿Me estoy perdiendo y tengo que agregar algún paquete?

Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba asignando una dirección base (dn).

```
Meteor.startup( function() {
    LDAP_DEFAULTS.url = 'ldap://ldap.*************.es';
    LDAP_DEFAULTS.dn = 'ou=<foo>,dc=<bar>,dc=<baz>,dc=<qux>';
    LDAP_DEFAULTS.port = 3189;
    LDAP_DEFAULTS.searchResultsProfileMap = [
        {
        resultKey: 'cn',
        profileProperty: 'name'
        }
        ,{
        resultKey: 'mail',
        profileProperty: 'phoneNumber'
        }
    ]
    });
```